# Stop while loop from repeating posts

Tags: php, while-loop

I am not really sure how to word this so if you need more clarification I can try my best to explain.

Here is the code

```
$file = "shout.txt";
$filed = file_get_contents($file);
preg_match_all('|<div class=\'date\'>(?P<date>.*?)&nbsp;.*<a.*>(?P<user>.*)</a>|i', $filed, $matches);

$shoutlines = file($shout_file);

$aTemp = array();
foreach($matches['user'] as $user) {
    $aTemp[] = "'" . mysql_real_escape_string($user) . "'";
}
$user = implode(",", $aTemp);

$getlevel = $db->query("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE username IN ( ".$user." )"); 
$isadmin = $db->query("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['username']."'");
$admin = $isadmin->fetch_assoc();
while($status = $getlevel->fetch_assoc()){
    //output the html
    for($i = 0; $i < (1000); $i++)
    {
        if(isset($shoutlines[$i]))
        {
            if ($admin['admin'] == 1 && $status['sblevel'] != Admin && $status['sblevel'] != Banned){
                $delete = "<a href='javascript: delete_shoutline({$i});' title='Delete' class='delete' onclick=\"return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this message?');\">x</a><a href='javascript: ban({$status['id']});' class='ban' onclick=\"return confirm('Are you sure you want to ban this user?');\">o</a>";
            }
            if ($admin['admin'] == 1 && $status['sblevel'] != Admin && $status['sblevel'] == Banned){
                $delete = "<a href='javascript: delete_shoutline({$i});' title='Delete' class='delete' onclick=\"return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this message?');\">x</a><a href='?index=shout&unban&user=".$shout['username']."' class='ban' onclick=\"return confirm('Are you sure you want to unban this user?');\">&oslash;</a>";
            }
            if ($admin['admin'] == 1 && $status['sblevel'] == Admin){
                $delete = "<a href='javascript: delete_shoutline({$i});' title='Delete' class='delete' onclick=\"return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this message?');\">x</a>";
            }
            if ($admin['sblevel'] == Moderator && $status['sblevel'] != Admin && $status['sblevel'] != Moderator){
                $delete = "<a href='javascript: delete_shoutline({$i});' title='Delete' class='delete' onclick=\"return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this message?');\">x</a><a href='?index=shout&ban&user=".$shout['username']."' class='ban' onclick=\"return confirm('Are you sure you want to ban this user?');\">o</a>";
            }
            if ($status['sblevel'] == Moderator  && $status['sblevel'] != Admin){
                $delete = "<a href='javascript: delete_shoutline({$i});' title='Delete' class='delete' onclick=\"return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this message?');\">x</a>";
            }
            $shoutline = preg_replace('/<\/div>\n/', ' ', $shoutlines[$i], 1);
            echo showSmileys($shoutline) . $delete . "</div>";
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that it duplicates all of the posts for every user that posted.. I am assuming this is because it is in a while loop, but I don't know how else to go about doing it because I need to check if a user is an admin/mod and if they are put a delete/ban button next to the posts to allow them to delete. As it stands now it puts an delete button next to all posts and then duplicates them all with a delete and ban button next to them.

Comment: Just a side question: Why do you use a text file instead of using mysql (you get the users with mysql)? If the file grows your memory usage will grow, the same for your load times.

Comment: What is the for loop doing?

Comment: Any reason why all those `if` statements aren't `else if`s?

Comment: @John he is using PDO `$isadmin = $db->query("SELECT ... ");`

Comment: @John the file automatically deletes the posts to only leave 100 posts at a time.

Comment: @Lenin look at line 5 (file() called)

Comment: @justderb I have tried `elseif` it does the same thing

Comment: @kira423 I think the point was more that if you only want one of them to execute anyway, you should use elseif because it's more efficient (as it doesn't have to check every condition after it's found the one you want).

Comment: Are the duplicates also in the text file? If so, you need to look at the page where they can post, not at the output.

Comment: @ValeraLeontyev he is storing smileys in the file probably.

Comment: @John no there is no duplicated in the text file

Comment: @Lenin no there is not smileys in that file, it is the posts that are stored in the file and I am not a he

Comment: What is in method `showSmileys` ?

Comment: It just uses `preg_match` and `preg_replace` to change things such as :) to an actual image, it has nothing to do with the error

Comment: When you say `//output the html`, you aren't posting the whole page before you add the moderator lines in to the page html are you? Because that would do what you described.

Comment: The problem seems to be that you're displaying ALL messages, not just the messages from that user. Your `for` loop needs to check whether the `$status['username']` is the author of the message in question.

Comment: @Barmar and I can do this properly how, because I want to say I tried putting in a check for that and it didn't work, but I could have done it wrong

Comment: Without knowing the structure of the shout_file, I can't help there. Putting the shout messages in the database would make it easier.

Comment: @Barmar well the thing is, I already have a shoutbox that uses the database instead of a flat file, and it is using a mass amount of CPU on my server, I have a question about it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13772212/high-cpu-usage-due-to-ajax-shoutbox . I actually paid for the one I am trying to use now, but it wasn't made for what I am attempting to do with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the simplest modification to avoid repeating messages. You have to supply a function `author()` that takes a line from the shout_file and returns the author ID.

```
while($status = $getlevel->fetch_assoc()){
    //output the html
    for($i = 0; $i < (1000); $i++)
    {
        if(isset($shoutlines[$i]))
        {
            if (author($shoutlines[$i]) != $status['id']) {
                continue;
            }
            if ($admin['admin'] == 1 && $status['sblevel'] != Admin && $status['sblevel'] != Banned){
                $delete = "<a href='javascript: delete_shoutline({$i});' title='Delete' class='delete' onclick=\"return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this message?');\">x</a><a href='javascript: ban({$status['id']});' class='ban' onclick=\"return confirm('Are you sure you want to ban this user?');\">o</a>";
            }
            if ($admin['admin'] == 1 && $status['sblevel'] != Admin && $status['sblevel'] == Banned){
                $delete = "<a href='javascript: delete_shoutline({$i});' title='Delete' class='delete' onclick=\"return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this message?');\">x</a><a href='?index=shout&unban&user=".$shout['username']."' class='ban' onclick=\"return confirm('Are you sure you want to unban this user?');\">&oslash;</a>";
            }
            if ($admin['admin'] == 1 && $status['sblevel'] == Admin){
                $delete = "<a href='javascript: delete_shoutline({$i});' title='Delete' class='delete' onclick=\"return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this message?');\">x</a>";
            }
            if ($admin['sblevel'] == Moderator && $status['sblevel'] != Admin && $status['sblevel'] != Moderator){
                $delete = "<a href='javascript: delete_shoutline({$i});' title='Delete' class='delete' onclick=\"return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this message?');\">x</a><a href='?index=shout&ban&user=".$shout['username']."' class='ban' onclick=\"return confirm('Are you sure you want to ban this user?');\">o</a>";
            }
            if ($status['sblevel'] == Moderator  && $status['sblevel'] != Admin){
                $delete = "<a href='javascript: delete_shoutline({$i});' title='Delete' class='delete' onclick=\"return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this message?');\">x</a>";
            }
            $shoutline = preg_replace('/<\/div>\n/', ' ', $shoutlines[$i], 1);
            echo showSmileys($shoutline) . $delete . "</div>";
            unset($shoutlines[$i]);
        }
    }
}
```

This probably isn't the best way to do it, since it repeats the "Ban this user" for each messages from the author. It would be better to put the ban/unban options once at the beginning of each user, then "delete" on each line.